# Subfloor revamp in 1950’s apt bathroom

Tags: bathroom, tile, subfloor

Laying tile and hoping  to understand optimal sub-floor solution in a 1950’s apartment bathroom. I removed the following top floor layers: sheet linoleum, linoleum tile, 3/8 plywood.  What is remaining: 3/4”x 4” sleeper battens spaced 4” apart laying on 0.5” particleboard, which is on top of 45 degree 1x6 planks laid with 1/4 spacing.

Options being considered:

**A:** New plywood (3/8) on top of sleepers, ditra, tile. This raises my floor 0.5” requiring door trim, toilet flange spacers. **Is 3/8 enough?** Do i need exterior grade or is interior fine given all that air space under? Screa through sleepers+Particle to the diagonal sub-floor planks or leave the sleepers floating?

**B:** Remove sleepers and put 1/2” plywood on top of particle. This puts my door and toilet flange at grade. PITA cutting the sleepers off at the counter edge but another hour on my belly with won’t kill me LOL.

How should I screw the 1/2” to the planks through particle board.

If you got other ideas, shoot me now LOL...

[image]

Comment: The sleepers are not necessary and the space between them is not conducive to a **stable, solid base** for a tile floor.

Comment: Thanks!  So plywood directly on top of particle board? Any recommendations for minimum thickness and screw method?